# Reference grouping columns as x-axis in pyplot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
custid  province    year    features... label
123     AB          2005    ...         0
124     ON          2006    ...         1
...
999     QC          2012    ...         1
```

The last column is the label / target.

I have a lambda function:

```
def churn_per_feature(x):
    d = {}
    d['churn_count'] = (x['label'] == 1).sum()
    d['cust_count'] = x['custid'].nunique()
    d['churn_rate'] = d['churn_count'] / float(d['cust_count'])
    return pd.Series(d, index = ['churn_count', 'cust_count', 'churn_rate'])
```

I have a grouping for two variables, `province` and `year`:

```
churn_per_province_year = df.groupby(['province', 'year']).apply(churn_per_feature)
```

I am attempting to `pyplot` this, a single chart with lines, where the x-axis is the `years` and each line represents the `province` (so far I am only selecting 4 province with biggest customer count, so it's not in a loop):

```
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'ON']['cust_count'])
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'AB']['cust_count'])
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'BC']['cust_count'])
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'QC']['cust_count'])
plt.show()
```

I don't know how to reference the `years` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like the following?

```
df.groupby(['year', 'province']).apply(churn_per_feature)['cust_count'].unstack().plot(legend=True)
```

[image]

With `matplotlib plt.plot()`:

```
churn_per_province_year = df.groupby(['year', 'province']).apply(churn_per_feature).reset_index()
#from matplotlib import pyplot
#years = range(2005, 2019) # add the right range here
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'ON']['cust_count'], label='ON')
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'AB']['cust_count'], label='AB')
plt.plot(years, churn_per_province_year[churn_per_province_year['province'] == 'QC']['cust_count'], label='QC')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how to do it by using the above formula? `plt.plot(<reference-year-here>, ...)`

Comment: using `pandas` plot it's easier to plot with a single line of code (which internally called `matplotlib`'s plot. Why do you want to use `matplotlib` plot instead?

Comment: I often encounter two ways to do this: invoking plotting function from the dataframe itself (`some_df.plot`) or using the plt function (`plt.plot(some_df...)`). I want to stick to using the second one as I am a beginner at matplotlib and this confuses me. Maybe after I mastered the plt and fully grokked how it works, I will switch to the first method.